# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in chemin/index.php on line 52

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I have a problem with my query : `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in chemin/index.php on line 52`

Here is my code :

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="box-top">Activité</div>
    <div class="box-panel">
        Dernières messages
        <p><strong>Utilisateur</strong> : 
        <?php
            $usernamelastmsg = $pdo->query('SELECT pseudo, message FROM chat');
            $affichagemessages = $usernamelastmsg->fetch($affichagemessages); 
            echo $affichagemessages['username'];
        ?>                      
        <br />
        Message :                       
        </p>                        
    </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: $affichagemessages->username

Comment: you only posted 11 lines, which one is line #52? what is $affichagemessages ?

Comment: @devpro, nice catch :)

Comment: @ryan-vincent one more issue where is username in select query :)

Comment: I am also confuse about this  $usernamelastmsg->fetch($affichagemessages);

Answer (score 2):

First of all check what are you getting in

```
var_dump($affichagemessages);
```

This should be an object not an array if you get result in an object than replace this line:

```
echo $affichagemessages['username'];
```

Into:

```
echo $affichagemessages->username;
```

But most important think is that you are not selecting the `username` column in your SELECT Statement columns.

Comment: @lrtcfr plz chk var dump as I mentioned in answet

Comment: It's an object, not an array

Comment: @lrtcfr and what is the structure of object looks like?

Comment: I don't understand :(

Comment: @Lrtcfr: just var_dump($affichagemessages); and share the result.